# How To Rename File Name on Uploading An Image Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can rename uploaded image name before sending to server?

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#uploadimage").on('submit', (function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#message").empty();
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_php_file.php", // Url to which the request is send
            type: "POST", // Type of request to be send, called as method
            data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
            contentType: false, // The content type used when sending data to the server.
            cache: false, // To unable request pages to be cached
            processData: false, // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
            success: function (data) // A function to be called if request succeeds
            {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $("#message").html(data);
            }
        });
    }));

    // Function to preview image after validation
    $(function () {
        $("#file").change(function () {
            $("#message").empty(); // To remove the previous error message
            var file = this.files[0];
            var imagefile = file.type;
            var match = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg"];
            if (!((imagefile == match[0]) || (imagefile == match[1]) || (imagefile == match[2]))) {
                $('#previewing').attr('src', 'noimage.png');
                $("#message").html("<p id='error'>Please Select A valid Image File</p>" + "<h4>Note</h4>" + "<span id='error_message'>Only jpeg, jpg and png Images type allowed</span>");
                return false;
            } else {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }
        });
    });

    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $("#file").css("color", "green");
        $('#image_preview').css("display", "block");
        $('#previewing').attr('src', e.target.result);
        //                    $('#previewing').attr('width', '250px');
        //                    $('#previewing').attr('height', '230px');
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="uploadimage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="image_spreview">
        <img id="previewing" src="" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" />
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <input class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="file" name="file" id="file" required />
    </div>
    <!-- Start of Uploader-->
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi mins, I tried to append some value to `formdata` object like this `                         var name =  $("#fileName").val();
                             var formData = new FormData(this);
                            formData.append("fileNewName", name);
                             console.log(formData);` but it didn't work!